# Office Professional 2016 Excel Office.js Add-in Browser Issue

Tags: excel, browser, office-js, add-in, excel-2016

The Add-in was working fine under Internet Explorer 11 and I was able to reliably observe and debug its behavior in Visual Studio 2017. Recently after some automatic Windows/Office updates, I noticed that iexplore.exe was not being used as the host browser. This resulted
in not being able to know what process to attach to for debugging.

At this point, out of desperation I executed the following steps to  to set JS_DEBUG:

1. In a windows power shell window executed command
   Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost
2. The command listed the package information including full package name for Win32WebViewHost , which was 
   Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_10.0.18362.449_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
3. I then executed the following 
   setx JS_DEBUG Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_10.0.18362.449_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy

   After some poking I noticed that WWAHost.exe was being used as the browser. Now the add-in is deploying fine but is encountering strange errors.

Is it  possible that the above steps resulted in WWAHost.exe  as the browser being used to host the add-in. So wondering how to undo the above setting so Internet Explorer 11 is the browser used by Excel to host the add-in.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control which browser is used to host the add-in. Office decides that. For details how this is determined, see the article: [Browsers used by Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins).